# Need a hello world for jPList to work with PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php

I have my local server running where I have pasted, inside the 'www/jpdemo', the 'server' folder contents of jPList Git repo https://github.com/1rosehip/jplist.

By following the usage example for php-mysql datasource http://jplist.com/datasources/php-mysql-data-source I have populated the DB and made my 'jpdemo/layout.html' with content as shown below.

What I am not getting is how to get the server side data once the HTML file is running, because no PHP script is being invoked anywhere, and I am getting a 'No results found' in the div output area of the webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello world</title>

    <!-- jquery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jpList head -->
                <!-- jPList core -->        
            <link href="jplist-core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="jplist-core.min.js"></script>  
            <!-- sort bundle -->
            <script src="/content/js/jplist/jplist.sort-bundle.min.js"></script>
            <!-- textbox filter control -->
            <script src="/content/js/jplist/jplist.textbox-control.min.js"></script>
            <link href="/content/css/jplist-textbox-control.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <!-- jPList pagination bundle -->
            <script src="/content/js/jplist/jplist.pagination-bundle.min.js"></script>
            <link href="/content/css/jplist-pagination-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />      
            <!-- jPList history bundle -->
            <script src="/content/js/jplist/jplist.history-bundle.min.js"></script>
            <link href="/content/css/jplist-history-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <!-- jPList toggle bundle -->
            <script src="/content/js/jplist/jplist.filter-toggle-bundle.min.js"></script>
            <link href="/content/css/jplist-filter-toggle-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <!-- jPList views control -->
            <script src="/content/js/jplist/jplist.views-control.min.js"></script>
            <link href="/content/css/jplist-views-control.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <!-- jPList preloader control -->
            <script src="/content/js/jplist/jplist.preloader-control.min.js"></script>
            <link href="/content/css/jplist-preloader-control.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <!-- Handlebars Templates Library: http://handlebarsjs.com -->
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.4/handlebars.min.js"></script>


            <!-- template library headers ->
            <!-- 
                Any other templates library could be used. 
                Also it can be used without javascript templates at all with plain HTML, 
                or as XML with XSLT.
                -->     

                <!-- Handlebars Templates Library: http://handlebarsjs.com -->
                <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.4/handlebars.min.js"></script>
                <!-- handlebars template -->
                <script id="jplist-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                   {{#each this}}

                      <div class="list-item box">   
                         <div class="img left">
                            <img src="{{image}}" alt="" title=""/>
                         </div>

                         <div class="block right">
                            <p class="title">{{title}}</p>
                            <p class="desc">{{description}}</p>
                            <p class="like">{{likes}} Likes</p>
                            <p class="theme">{{keyword1}}, {{keyword2}}</p>
                         </div>
                      </div>

                   {{/each}}
                </script>   

</head>
<body>
        <script>
               $('document').ready(function () {
                  var $list = $('#demo .list')
                     ,template = Handlebars.compile($('#jplist-template').html());
                  $('#demo').jplist({
                     itemsBox: '.list'
                     ,itemPath: '.list-item'
                     ,panelPath: '.jplist-panel'
                     //data source
                     ,dataSource: {
                        type: 'server'
                        ,server: {
                        //ajax settings
                        ajax: {
                           url: 'server-json.php'
                           ,dataType: 'json'
                           ,type: 'POST'
                        }
                     }
                     //render function for json + templates like handlebars, xml + xslt etc.
                     ,render: function (dataItem, statuses) {
                        $list.html(template(dataItem.content));
                     }
                  }
                  });
               });
        </script>

        <!-- demo -->
                    <div id="demo">

                       <!-- panel -->
                       <div class="jplist-panel">                       

                          <!-- reset button -->
                          <button 
                             type="button" 
                             class="jplist-reset-btn"
                             data-control-type="reset" 
                             data-control-name="reset" 
                             data-control-action="reset">
                             Reset  <i class="fa fa-share"></i>
                          </button>
                          <!-- items per page dropdown -->
                          <div
                             class="jplist-drop-down"
                             data-control-type="items-per-page-drop-down"
                             data-control-name="paging"
                             data-control-action="paging">
                             <ul>
                                <li><span data-number="3"> 3 per page </span></li>
                                <li><span data-number="5"> 5 per page </span></li>
                                <li><span data-number="10" data-default="true"> 10 per page </span></li>
                                <li><span data-number="all"> View All </span></li>
                             </ul>
                          </div>
                          <!-- sort dropdown -->
                          <div
                             class="jplist-drop-down"
                             data-control-type="sort-drop-down"
                             data-control-name="sort"
                             data-control-action="sort">
                             <ul>
                                <li><span data-path="default">Sort by</span></li>
                                <li><span data-path=".title" data-order="asc" data-type="text">Title A-Z</span></li>
                                <li><span data-path=".title" data-order="desc" data-type="text">Title Z-A</span></li>
                                <li><span data-path=".desc" data-order="asc" data-type="text">Description A-Z</span></li>
                                <li><span data-path=".desc" data-order="desc" data-type="text">Description Z-A</span></li>
                                <li><span data-path=".like" data-order="asc" data-type="number">Likes asc</span></li>
                                <li><span data-path=".like" data-order="desc" data-type="number">Likes desc</span></li>
                             </ul>
                          </div>
                          <!-- text filter by title -->
                          <div class="text-filter-box">

                             <!--[if lt IE 10]>
                             <div class="jplist-label">Filter by Title:</div>
                             <![endif]-->

                             <input 
                                data-path=".title" 
                                data-button="#title-search-button"
                                type="text" 
                                value="" 
                                placeholder="Filter by Title" 
                                data-control-type="textbox" 
                                data-control-name="title-filter" 
                                data-control-action="filter"
                             />

                             <button 
                                type="button" 
                                id="title-search-button">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                             </button>
                          </div>

                          <!-- text filter by description -->
                          <div class="text-filter-box">

                             <!--[if lt IE 10]>
                             <div class="jplist-label">Filter by Description:</div>
                             <![endif]-->

                             <input 
                                data-path=".desc" 
                                data-button="#desc-search-button"
                                type="text" 
                                value="" 
                                placeholder="Filter by Description" 
                                data-control-type="textbox" 
                                data-control-name="desc-filter" 
                                data-control-action="filter"
                             /> 

                             <button 
                                type="button" 
                                id="desc-search-button">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                             </button>
                          </div>

                          <!-- checkbox filters -->
                          <div
                             class="jplist-group"
                             data-control-type="checkbox-group-filter"
                             data-control-action="filter"
                             data-control-name="themes">
                             <input
                                data-path=".architecture"
                                id="architecture"
                                type="checkbox"
                             />
                             <label for="architecture">Architecture</label>
                             <input
                                data-path=".christmas"
                                id="christmas"
                                type="checkbox"
                             />
                             <label for="christmas">Christmas</label>
                             <input
                                data-path=".nature"
                                id="nature"
                                type="checkbox"
                             />
                             <label for="nature">Nature</label>
                             <input
                                data-path=".lifestyle"
                                id="lifestyle"
                                type="checkbox"
                             />
                             <label for="lifestyle">Lifestyle</label>
                          </div>
                          <div
                             class="jplist-group"
                             data-control-type="checkbox-group-filter"
                             data-control-action="filter"
                             data-control-name="colors">
                             <input
                                data-path=".red"
                                id="red-color"
                                type="checkbox"
                             />
                             <label for="red-color">Red</label>
                             <input
                                data-path=".green"
                                id="green-color"
                                type="checkbox"
                             />
                             <label for="green-color">Green</label>
                             <input
                                data-path=".blue"
                                id="blue-color"
                                type="checkbox"
                             />
                             <label for="blue-color">Blue</label>
                             <input
                                data-path=".brown"
                                id="brown-color"
                                type="checkbox"
                             />
                             <label for="brown-color">Brown</label>

                          </div>
                          <!-- list / grid view -->
                          <div 
                             class="jplist-views" 
                             data-control-type="views" 
                             data-control-name="views" 
                             data-control-action="views"
                             data-default="jplist-list-view">

                             <button type="button" class="jplist-view jplist-list-view" data-type="jplist-list-view"></button>
                             <button type="button" class="jplist-view jplist-grid-view" data-type="jplist-grid-view"></button>
                          </div>

                          <!-- pagination results -->
                          <div 
                             class="jplist-label" 
                             data-type="Page {current} of {pages}" 
                             data-control-type="pagination-info" 
                             data-control-name="paging" 
                             data-control-action="paging">
                          </div>

                          <!-- pagination -->
                          <div 
                             class="jplist-pagination" 
                             data-control-type="pagination" 
                             data-control-name="paging" 
                             data-control-action="paging">
                          </div>    
                          <!-- preloader for data sources -->
                          <div 
                             class="jplist-hide-preloader jplist-preloader"
                             data-control-type="preloader" 
                             data-control-name="preloader" 
                             data-control-action="preloader">
                             <img src="/content/img/common/ajax-loader-line.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />
                          </div>        

                       </div>                

                       <!-- HTML data -->   
                       <div class="list">

                          <!-- item 1 -->
                          <div class="list-item">   
                             ...
                          </div>

                          <!-- item 2 -->
                          <div class="list-item">   
                             ...
                          </div>

                          ...

                       </div>

                       <!-- no results found -->
                       <div class="jplist-no-results">
                          <p>No results found</p>
                       </div>

                    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I checked the console log. Resources were not in the proper location on the server and I tried to reduce the disparity by looking at the log and putting the files(from the repo - js/css/img files) in the server target locations. I checked the logs in FF now as only JS errors:

```
TypeError: jQuery.fn.jplist is undefined[Learn More]  jplist.sort-bundle.min.js:6:123
TypeError: jQuery.fn.jplist is undefined[Learn More]  jplist.pagination-bundle.min.js:6:87
TypeError: jQuery.fn.jplist is undefined[Learn More]  jplist.history-bundle.min.js:6:194
TypeError: jQuery.fn.jplist is undefined[Learn More]  jplist.filter-toggle-bundle.min.js:9:371
TypeError: jQuery.fn.jplist is undefined[Learn More]  jplist.preloader-control.min.js:5:434
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.  layout.html
TypeError: $(...).jplist is not a function[Learn More]  layout.html:73:10
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**
By looking at the errors(not the above!) I guess that the **jplist-master** folder grom git has to exist inside the www folder. I did this and queried for the demo pages therein 
for php-mysql. There is no error in chrome console. Everything is displayed correctly except that data from mysql isn't getting populated in the divs and it shows "No results found". I have tested connectivity with other php-mysql projects as working and the config.php in jplist-master has correct connection parameters. Also the DB was populated with the provided SQL statements only.

Comment: `url: 'server-json.php'` loads the php script, using ajax. Do you get any errors? Checked the console log?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I have edited the details, posted the latest error logs.